# Using Angular Ionic and node.js - how to listen to the server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, server

I am relatively new to node.js and super new to Ionic and am super confused. As I was looking online for answers, I came across one blog which would say that I have to runnodejs server using node (in my case)  nam start and the app using ionic serve, so lets say I am listening on port 3000, it wouldn't be http://localhost:3000 but something like http://123.456.789.123:3000

1. I assume that both must listen on the same port?! so if my node.js is listening on port 3000, my ionic must listen on 3000 too?
2. Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729

Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100

I don't understand what  http://localhost:35729 means - is it correct to say that Im listening on port 8100

3. I tried to set my node.js server to listen on port 8100 (probably all wrong what I did) and it doesn't work- can't see anything when I type ip address::8100

Thank you!!

Comment: A code example of your node script would be helpful. Also, what you are trying to accomplish? Ionic is for the UI of mobile apps and node.js is a server technology like PHP. Why are you using node.js with your Ionic app instead of using API's on the phone/tablet?

Comment: I don't know how to use api's and as I was learning node for the backend I just wanted to use that - wouldn't know how to connect to the database also otherwise. I m not sure what part of my code would be good- my only question is what to run -if node runs on one port and ionic on another - how to connect?

Comment: My Friend you can use Ionic without node, just make dist folder with gulp and deploy it to a wamp or xamp server you can access just writing the URL where you copy you code.

Comment: and how do i write code for the backend then?